# How to render a height map using OpenGL / cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I have a 2d array of floats. Each cell represents a pixel.
Depending on the value of the float, I map the float to a particular colour.
I want to generate a background sprite based on all these values. I don't know much about OpenGL, so I don't know where to start.

**Given a 2d array of pixels. How does one create a sprite?**

**Once done with this sprite, how does one release the texture and sprite from memory ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a [CGImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) from your data and then use that to initialize a cocos2d sprite.

```
// Create a graphics context from the heightmap data
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(myArray,   // heightmap data
                                             width,     // width of hightmap
                                             height,    // height of heightmap
                                             8,         // bits per component
                                             width * 4, // bytes per row
                                             colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

// Create an image from the context
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);

// Init sprite
CCSprite *sprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithCGImage:image key:nil];
CGImageRelease(image);
```